# Probability that $|z_1+z_2|\geq \sqrt{2+\sqrt 3}$

Tags: probability, complex-numbers

> $z_1$ and $z_2$ are two distinct roots of $z^{101}=1$. Find the probability that $|z_1+z_2|\geq \sqrt{2+\sqrt 3}$
>
> Answer: $\frac{4}{25}$

**My attempt:**

Let $z_1=\exp\left(i\cdot \frac{2m\pi}{101}\right)$ and $z_2=\exp\left(i\cdot \frac{2k\pi}{101}\right)$ with $m\neq k$ and $m,k\in \{0,1,\cdots ,100\}$.

Using this the given equation becomes
$$\sqrt{2+2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi(m-k)}{101}\right)}\geq \sqrt{2+\sqrt 3}$$
From here I got,
$$|m-k|\leq \frac{101}{12}$$
Since $m,k$ are integers,
$$|m-k|\leq 8$$

My attempt matches with the given solution upto this point. But then, as I'm stuck with how to calculate the probability. The given solution gets
$$P=\frac{101\cdot 16}{101\cdot 100}$$
in the very next step and I'm unable to understand why.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

**Edit: My thoughts on calculating the probability**

WLOG assume $m>k$.

- For $k=0$, values for $m$ are $1,2,\cdots 8$
- For $k=1$, values for $m$ are $2,3,\cdots 9$

And so on

- For $k=92$, values for $m$ are $93,94,\cdots 100$

Till here, each value of $k$ gives $8$ values of $m$. But from here onwards, that isn't the case.

- For $k=93$, values for $m$ are $94,95,\cdots 100$

And so on.

Thus, the "favourable" cases are $93\times 8 +7+6+5×4+3+2+1$ while the sample space has $100+99+\cdots +1$ elements. This gives the probability $\frac {772}{4950}$ which doesn't match.

Comment: $m$ can be any number between 0 and 100, while $k$ must be $m+1,...,m+8$ or $m-1,...,m-8$ and it's known that $k$ is different than $m$. So it's 16/100 (good values / total values). I think you are messing up becasue you are assuming that $k$ belongs to {0,...100}, but you should consider the periodicity. Think about the polygon with the solutions

Comment: @Naj Kamp : I have added my attempt. Please go through it and let me know your thoughts. Also, I think the solution $k=2,m=3$ is same as $k=3,m=2$.

Comment: For $k=0$,  $m=100$ works. Can you see why? And can you see what's wrong with your reasonings?

Comment: @Naj Kami Oooh, I see now- both me and the solution giver went from $$\cos \left(\frac{2\pi(m-k)}{101}\right)\geq\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}=\cos \pi/6$$ to $$|m-k|\geq 101/12$$ though it holds for $\cos 11\pi/6$ as well which gives us $|m-k|\geq 93$ as well. BTW I was about the edit: my thoughts on the probability calculation. (P.S. Is it right if we restrict it to $|m-k|\leq 8$? If not, where did I go wrong?)

Comment: There is no need to split into the cases where $k$ is near $100$ since the values of $m$ and $k$ only matter modulo $101$ due to the periodicity of $\cos$. For example when $k = 94$, the values $m = 95, \ldots, 101, 102$ all work. But since we insist that $0 \leq m \leq 100$, we can replace the cases $m = 101$ and $m = 102$ with their equivalent values $m= 0 $ and $m= 1$ modulo $101$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix one vertex intially say $k=0$. Then $m$ can take the values $1,2, \ldots 8$, $-1,-2,\ldots,-8$(or $100,99,\ldots 93$) . Amounting to a total of $16$ ways.

Now the first vertex(k) can be shifted to the **other** $100$ vertices, and in each case there are $16$ corresponding values of $m$.
Note that this approach includes the vertices as ordered pairs, i.e. making the choice of value $(m,k)$ different from $(k,m)$.

Hence the total number of outcomes, most also be made according to unordered pairs, which is ${101 \choose 2} \times 2 = 100 \times 101$.

Hence the required probability is $P= \frac{16 \times 101}{101 \times 100}= \frac{4}{25}$

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Think of $m$ as fixed. Then since $m$ and $k$ are distinct, there are $100$ possibilities for $k$.

Now the condition $|m-k| \leq 8$ means $|m-k| = n$ for some integer $n \in [1,8]$. Each value of $n$ gives rise to two solutions for $k$, and there are $8$ possible values of $n$.

Can you finish it from here?

---

Note also that technically the requirement on $m$ and $k$ is slightly different from $|m-k| \leq 8$. The actual requirement is that $|m-k| \equiv n \pmod{101}$ for some positive integer $n \leq 8$, and this takes care of the cases near the boundary.

Comment: Uhh, each value of $n$ doesn't give rise to two solutions for $k$. Here, the set $(m,k)$ is unordered. If you are able to understand what I want to say.

Comment: I understand the pairs $(m,k)$ are unordered, but I mean to say that the equation $|m-k| = n$ determines the two solutions $k = m \pm n$ for $k$. And if this returns a value of $k$ outside of the range $[0, 100]$, then $101$ can be added to or subtracted from it to give a value inside the range that corresponds to a valid solution. However I agree this is a little messy